# Why does going close to the speed of light make almost everything look like it's directly ahead of you

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Why does going close to the speed of light make almost everything look like it's directly ahead of you?
I understand why there's SOME shift in the direction that the light appears to come from, by I can't understand why an object that would appear at 90 degrees relative to your motion when you are going slowly would appear less then 45 degrees away from directly ahead when you are moving close to the speed of light.

Comment: Where did you hear/read that?

Comment: See the discussion in section 1.3 of [this](https://www.amazon.in/Spinors-Space-Time-Two-Spinor-Relativistic-Mathematical/dp/0521337070) for description in Minkowski space-time, and section 8.2 of [this](https://www.amazon.in/Spinors-Space-Time-Cambridge-Monographs-Mathematical/dp/0521347866) (for curved space-time)

Comment: Are you referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation ? See https://www.spacetimetravel.org/ueberblick/ueberblick1.html and https://www.spacetimetravel.org/bewegung/bewegung.html

Comment: aberration of light - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberration_%28astronomy%29

Answer (score 0):

Slowly moving person says: "the light that I see now left the object some time ago, the object was then to the right side of me. That's why I see the object at this particular direction".

Fast moving person says: "the light that I see now left the object quite long time ago, the object was then quite far ahead of me. That's why I see the object at this particular direction".

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly you are referring to relativistic length contraction. As you nearing the speed of light $c$, all the scenery in front of you is also travelling relativistically at speed $c$ towards you.

This will trigger the relativistic effect of [length contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction) where all objects you see will be contracted in size towards the direction of travel consequently giving you a tunnel effect vision of the scenery ahead of you.

[image]

Comment: Length contraction says that "all objects you see" will be contracted in size _behind_ you as well, and that does not happen!  Technically, you need to use _two_ spatial dimensions to describe what you see.  Details here: https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s2-05/2-05.htm